# How to implement button/link in dispform.aspx to start list workflow?

Tags: 2013, list, workflow

I am using SharePoint  2013. I have a list and a workflow on this list. I have created a custom action in the ribbon which is starting this workflow. I dont want this button in the ribbon.

I would like to implement a link or button in my dispForm.aspx. This is the link how it is now from the custom action in the ribbon:

```
http://myCompany.com/_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={9bb58a2b-e9c0-412c-9ce2-86ae8c1c570f}&ID=13&ItemGuid={A3747767-CBB8-4ACC-BCE3-9CD659E97BF3}&TemplateID={30d52657-83b4-4b14-b484-098f650311e7}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily call this best practice but you could edit dispform.aspx and add a CEWP that includes a HTML button to your workflow.

[image: Edit Default Display Form]
[image: Add Web Part]

Comment: yes thats the easiest part. But how do I need to implement the link or button. In the link I need the listitemid and listid. How can I set them dynamicaly?